Summing Python array values
I am new to programming and trying to learn with python. I have this code and expecting to sum the values of an array but getting error.
TypeError: sum_array() takes 1 positional argument but 5 were given

I have this code that I managed to write based on the things i learned online
def sum_array(arr):

    total = 0
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        total += arr[i]

    return total

result = sum_array(1,2,3,4,5)  
print("Sum of array:", result)`

I am at lost. Sorry if this is a beginners question

And the error message you get is what exactly? We can guess, but don’t make us.

Should be
result = sum_array([1,2,3,4,5])

a list.

*a list. Python uses lists.

This answer needs more details. It's good that you posted code that works, but explaining why it works is always a valuable addition.
